# Custom UITableView section header, weird behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using a custom header view for the section headers in a UITableView. Here are a couple of dataSource methods:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    SBTableViewHeader *header = [[SBTableViewHeader alloc] init];
    header.titleLabel.text = self.earnings;
    header.subtitleLabel.text = @"You have earned $23 today.";
    return header;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 90;
}
```

I know that my header view is supposed to be 90 points high, but instead I'm getting 90 points of my header view PLUS another 90 empty points of space, which cover some of the cells. That's 180 total, measured it in Photoshop.

Help!

Some more info: SBTableViewHeader is a UIView subclass and is using a .xib. Nothing special there. File's Owner is set to SBTableViewHeader and everything else seems to be connected properly.

Comment: Check the height of your view in the xib file. It should also be 90 points.

Comment: Have you checked that `[[SBTableViewHeader alloc] init]` returns a view with height=90?

Comment: I checked it, it's 90.

Comment: @MartinR That was the issue! It returned a view with frame and bounds with 0 height, so the solution was to use initWithFrame: instead of init: ... Feel free to post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(From the comments:)*

You have to use `initWithFrame` instead of `init` to create a view with the correct size.

`heightForHeaderInSection:` (and similarly `heightForRowAtIndexPath`) is used by the table view only to compute header and cell positions, the size of the scroll indicator etc.

The data source (or delegate) methods have to return cells/views of the correct size, otherwise they will overlap with other items.